# React map function: how to output content of all nested arrays at once?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, jsx

My data is an object with key value pairs and then some arrays ("skill_1" and "skill_2") with strings:

```
const HeroDescriptions = [
  {
    id: "ana",
    name: "Ana",
    role: "Support",
      skill_1: [
        "Biotic Rifle",
        "Damage: 70",
        "Healing: 75"
      ],
      skill_2: [
        "Biotic Grenade",
        "Damage: 60",
        "Healing: 100"
      ]
    }
  ]
```

I output this to JSX like that:

```
const content = description.map(item => (
    <div key={item.id}>
      <h1>{item.name}</h1>
      <h2>Role: {item.role}</h2>
      <hr />
      <ul>
        {description[0].skill_1.map((skill, index) => (
          <li key={index}>{skill}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  ));

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>{content}</ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I would like to modify this snippet:

```
{description[0].skill_1.map((skill, index) => (
   <li key={index}>{skill}</li>
```

How could I loop through all nested skill arrays, so that my code would be reusable and would work, if there were e.g. 4 arrays with skills?

Comment: Try using a different data format: `{ "skills": [ { "name": "rifle", "damage": 70, "healing": 50 }, { "name": "knife", "damage": 15, "healing": 10 }] }` would make more sense. Then you do not have to know how many skills a hero has in the template and you can just map() the skills the same way you map() the descriptions. An added advantage is that you won't need to parse '70 damage' to an integer when calculating a shot.

Comment: You could use `Object.entries`, and `Array.filter` with a regex `/^skill_.*/`, and finally of course your `Array.map`  Or alternatively alter your structure like @Shilly points out..  :)

Comment: Why not to use array:
`skills: [
[
        "Biotic Rifle",
        "Damage: 70",
        "Healing: 75"
      ], [
        "Biotic Grenade",
        "Damage: 60",
        "Healing: 100"
      ]
]`

Comment: How would the approach change, if the skills were objects with key-value pairs rather than arrays? I tried following @Shilly 's approach, but the skills might differ for every character. E.g. healing is not always going to be available. I wonder If it would be possible to map through all the skills even if the keys are different among different heroes

Comment: A character in overwatch that can't heal with any skill, has a healing of 0 on all skills. The point is that healing should be a property of a skill object, even if it's zero. Having a fixed list of keys on everything, even if they have the value 0 or null or undefined, means you can hard code these properties and never have to use something like `Object.keys()` to check if a key is available on an object.So then the problem of 'mapping through all skills, even if they have different keys' does not exist anymore, since everything has the same keys, just with different values.

Comment: The benefit is that you can assume things you would otherwise check for. You never have to write something like : `if (hero.skill.healing ) hero.health += hero.healing;` You just write `hero.health += hero.skill.healing`, since if a hero uses a skill that gives 0 healing, the health total does not change. As written now, adding damage would be something like: `hero.health -= parseInt(hero.skill_1.split( ' ' )[1] , 10);` all because your skill is an array of strings where each string represents a key/value pair.

Comment: For the record, since all overwatch heroes have the same amount of skills, using skill_1 to skill_x is less important than if heroes had a variable amount of skills. Then again, if blizzard ever adds a character with like a dual ultimate, you would have the same issue again if you don't use a variable amount of skills, so I would still prefer to pretend heroes can have any number of skills to begin with, it's more future-proof.

Comment: @Shilly thanks for your detailed explanation. I now see how beneficial it can be to have well structured and consistent data. 
Previously, I was concerned that I will end up with empty list elements, if for example, there's a key of "knockback", and a certain character just doesn't have it. But it turns out, this can be easily controlled with CSS. If the given "knockback" is set to "none", I can use a css class of "none" set to to "display: none", and the list element won't be displayed.
Yeah, if blizzard adds new heroes, we want it to be easy to add new data too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your existing data structure, you can use [`spread`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) syntax to capture the skills together, and then using the `getSkills` method, [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) over each object's values to combine the arrays, and then [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over that set to produce your final list of skills.

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  getSkills(skills) {
    return Object.values(skills).reduce((acc, skillset) => {
      return [...acc, ...skillset];
    }, []).map(skill => <li>{skill}</li>);
  }

  render() {
 
   const { descriptions } = this.props;
 
   return (

     descriptions.map(params => {
       const { id, name, role, ...skills } = params;
       return (
         <div key={id}>
         <h1>{name}</h1>
         <h2>Role: {role}</h2>
         <hr />
         <ul>
           {this.getSkills(skills)}
         </ul>
         </div>
       );
     })
   );
  }
}

const descriptions = [{"id":"ana","name":"Ana","role":"Support","skill_1":["Biotic Rifle","Damage: 70","Healing: 75"],"skill_2":["Biotic Grenade","Damage: 60","Healing: 100"]}];

ReactDOM.render(
  <App descriptions={descriptions} />,
  document.querySelector('#app')
);
```

```css
.category { margin: 1em; }
h1 { font-size: 1em; font-weight: 600; }
h2 { font-size: 0.9em; font-weight: 600; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I implemented your solution. I'm in a functional component with hooks, so I omitted the "this" keyword

Answer (score 4):

Hello fellow Overwatch player :)

If you want to loop over keys of an object, you can use Object.keys method which is described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Your code block would become:

```
Object.keys(item)
  .filter(key => ['id', 'name', 'role'].indexOf === -1))  // filter out unrelated keys
  .map(skillKey => item[skillKey])
  .map(skillArr => <li key={skillArr[0]}>{skillArr.join(', ')}</li>)
```

P.S: You data object is not well formed. It would be better to have another field called 'skills' and loop over them

Comment: You can avoid your double `map`, if you use `Object.entries`..  `Object.entries(item).filter(([skillKey]) => ...).map(([_, skillArr]) => ...`

Comment: I feel it's more clear if you use only item or key at a time.  Especially when you have 2,3 map/filter tasks

Answer (score 2):

You may extract `skill_x` properties into array:

```js
const HeroDescriptions = [{
  id: "ana",
  name: "Ana",
  role: "Support",
  skill_1: [
   "Biotic Rifle",
   "Damage: 70",
   "Healing: 75"
  ],
  skill_2: [
   "Biotic Grenade",
   "Damage: 60",
   "Healing: 100"
  ]
 }
];

({id, name, role, ...skills} = HeroDescriptions[0]);

console.log(Object.values(skills));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

And I agree with above comments, reformatting those properties into something, like below, would make more sense:

```
{
    skill: 'Biotic Rifle',
    damage: 70,
    Healing: 75
}
```